# Are all of the CPUs that implement the AMD64 instruction set have the same instructions and registers?

Tags: assembly, x86, cpu, x86-64

The CPUs that implement the IA-32 instruction set (which is the 32-bit x86 instruction set) do not have the same instructions and registers, for example the Intel Pentium III have the SSE registers and instructions which are not present in the Intel Pentium II.

But what about the CPUs that implement the AMD64 instruction set (which is the 64-bit x86 instruction set), do these CPUs have the same instructions and registers (what I mean is: is there some AMD64 CPU that have more instructions and registers than another AMD64 CPU, in the same way that there are IA-32 CPUs that have more instructions and registers than other IA-32 CPUs)?

Comment: No, ISA extensions continue to exists in AMD64.

Comment: @Margaret Bloom Sorry my question wasn't very clear, I edited it to make it clearer.

Answer (score 2):

All AMD64 CPUs have the following features:

- the full i686 instruction set
- a full Pentium Pro compatible x87 FPU with MMX
- SSE, and SSE2

Some early AMD64 CPUs miss the `sahf` and `lahf` instructions in long mode.

Additional instruction set extensions such as SSE3, AVX, fisttp, and BMI are not guaranteed to be supported.

Comment: Sorry my question wasn't very clear, I edited it to make it clearer.

Comment: @user247763 To your updated question: the answer is yes.  For example, recent amd64 processors have AVX instructions or the `popcnt` instruction, all of which are absent from the baseline AMD64 specification.

Comment: @user247763: AVX512F is the clearest example of an extension that adds new registers: k0..k7 mask registers, and x/y/zmm16..31 accessible only with AVX512F instructions (using the EVEX encoding.)   AVX512VL (vector length) is required for xmm/ymm16..31 with just AVX512F you can *only* use 512-bit zmm registers.  (Or use VEX or legacy SSE for xmm/ymm 0..15).  Of course the upper half of zmm0..15 is also new architectural state that AVX didn't have.

Comment: There are other extensions, like [MPX added `bnd0` .. `bnd3`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_MPX) new architectural state, as well as new instructions to use them.

Answer (score 2):

Not everything is equal:

Intel's x86 CPUs support the `sysenter` instruction in 64-bit mode, AMD's CPUs (at least older ones) do not.

On the other hand AMD's CPUs support `syscall` in 32-bit mode, but Intel's 64-bit CPUs (at least older ones) do not.

I'm sure that this is not the only difference in existing and/or future AMD64 CPUs.